# Search with multiple criteria sometimes doesn't show results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Sometimes, when I do a search with two criteria, the search URL ends up containing a space (rather than a `+`), and then, sometimes, the server doesn't return the actual results, just the count and pagination. This is **semi-reproducible**: hitting reload may or may not return the results.

Here's example content returned from `http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=deleted%3a1%20hasaccepted%3a0` (obtained by searching `deleted:1 hasaccepted:0` and clicking on `next` to get the second page of results). Just now, the third page at `http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=deleted%3a1%20hasaccepted%3a0` works fine. The screenshot was in Chrome 11.0.696.48, but I've had the exact same bug in Firefox 4.0 (if there's any caching shared between them, my ISP is being extremely naughty). I haven't been able to reproduce the bug with a general-public search, but I stopped trying when I hit the search rate limit.

[image: screenshot with search missing results]

Comment: This is because `deleted:1`  is not a generally available search option, I'll fix the search results count display for this case.

Comment: @Nick: Just to be clear, I am a moderator on scifi.SE, so I should be seeing the results. And sometimes I do, sometimes I don't. I haven't had a problem before tonight.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear on my side: it's a caching issue for mod vs non-mod :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be safe on `deleted:` searches for moderators, that case needs it's own cache key to avoid conflict with another user running the same search.  This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: I still see the bug on build rev 2011.4.29.1.

Comment: And I still see the same behavior on build rev 2011.5.7.2. Or does the fix require me to log out and back in for some reason? If not, this is not fixed.

Comment: @Gilles - I'll take another look in the morning, been a busy day today, and about to head out again

Comment: No worries, as bugs go this is pretty minor. I think since your first change the behavior has become consistent: the first page of results always works the first time, and reloading it or loading other result pages shows “no matches” but the correct number of matches and result pages.

Comment: @Gilles - in a push later today this will be fixed for good, there are a lot of code paths here and `deleted:1` was slipping through in a particularly unusual way.